# #define string over multiple lines

Tags: c, string, c-preprocessor, string-literals, preprocessor-directive

I was wondering how I could define a really long string over the multiple lines.
I tried so many different patterns, but none of them is working..
Here is my code.

```
#define EXAMPLE "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
                "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
                "ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"
```

and I get syntax error.
The error I got is

```
ccompile.h (as included in test.c)
=================
error: syntax error before or at: g
*** Error code 2
```

I want to assign "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccccccdddddddd" to EXAMPLE.

I tried using \ and @\ but that didn't work out.

Comment: Edit in a [mcve] demonstrating the failure(s).

Comment: `@` is totally meaningless; I have no idea where that idea comes from. `\\`  only works if it is the last character on the line. When you are curious about something that "doesn't work", you must  (a) include the precise thing in the question and  (b) specify exactly what "doesn't work" means (including the exact error message, if that is the problem).

Comment: Please show the exact code that uses `\` that "does not work" and how it does not work.

Comment: Do you really need a string literal in a **macro**?  It's much better practice to assign it to a `const char *const` constant unless there's a compelling reason you need it available to the preprocessor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just get rid of the whitespace in between the lines, and quote the whole thing. A `\` at the EOL basically *"escapes"* the newline, so it won't be part of the string itself. It's only relevant for the preprocessor:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LONG_STRING "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"

int main ( void ) {
    printf(LONG_STRING);
    return 0;
}
```

That works [just fine](https://eval.in/737054)

For aesthetic reasons, you can quote each line separately, the only requirement is you add the `\` directly after the closing quotes:

```
#define LONG_STRING "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"\
                    "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"\
                    "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
```

This, too, works [just fine](https://eval.in/737057)

#### Note:

The two suggestions *are not* 100% equivalent. The first version defines a macro to be a single string literal. The second version defines the macro as 3 *separate* string literals. For the most part, this isn't a big deal, because during the translation phase, adjacent string literal tokens should be concatenated:

> 5.1.1.2 Translation phases:
>   [...]
>   6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.
>   7. White-space characters separating tokens are no longer significant. Each
>   preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens are
>   syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a translation unit.

I could not find the footnote Meninx mentions about C99 behaving differently. Document I used [can be found here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you!

Comment: @TobySpeight: You're right, I'll update pointing out the potential pitfalls

Answer (score 3):

```
#define EXAMPLE "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
                "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"
                "ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc"
                "ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"
```

For the directive above, its replacement list is limited only to `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"` because macro definition works only a **single logical line**.

Moreover, concatenating adjacent string literals to form a single one is not possible in C during **preprocessing**.

**C99 *footnote 148*:**

> <sub>148:   Note that adjacent string literals are not concatenated into a
>   single  string literal</sub>

Instead use the backslash-newline :

```
#define EXAMPLE "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc\
ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd"
```

**C99 5.1.1.2  p/2**

> 2. Each instance of a **backslash character () immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to
>      form logical source lines**. Only the last backslash on any physical
>      source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. A
>      source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which
>      shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any
>      such splicing takes place.